# Use an object of JFrame in a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a class in java that extends JFrame it shows Time :

```
class Clock extends JFrame implements Runnable{
Thread runner;
Font clockFont;
```

This code shows a Digital Clock

```
 public Clock()
 {
   super("Java clock");
   setSize( 350, 100);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);
   setResizable(false);                             

   clockFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40);    

   Container contentArea = getContentPane();
   ClockPanel timeDisplay = new ClockPanel();
   contentArea.add(timeDisplay);                    
   setContentPane(contentArea);
   start();                                         
 }
 class ClockPanel extends JPanel
 {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics painter )
    {
    Image pic =
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("background.jpg");

     if(pic != null){ 
      painter.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, this);     
      painter.setFont(clockFont);                   
      painter.setColor(Color.black);
      painter.drawString( timeNow(), 60, 40);
    }
 }

 public String timeNow()
 {
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
   int hrs = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   int min = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int sec = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

   String time = zero(hrs)+":"+zero(min)+":"+zero(sec);

   return time;
 }     
 public String zero(int num)
 {
   String number=( num < 10) ? ("0"+num) : (""+num);
   return number;                                    

 }
 public void start()
 {
   if(runner == null) runner = new Thread(this);
   runner.start();
 }
 public void run()
 {
   while (runner == Thread.currentThread() )
   {
    repaint();
       try
         {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
          catch(InterruptedException e)
              {
                System.out.println("Thread failed");
              }                 
   }
 }
```

Now I wanna show that clock in a `JPanel` in my other Frame , how can I add an object of Clock class in Jpanel ?!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"now i wanna ..Tnx .."*  What I want to see in a technical forum is people taking a little effort with spelling phrases like 'want to' & 'thanks', and using the shift key at the start of sentences.  :(

Comment: but it's not my answer exactly!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (logically indented). 2) Why have a 2nd frame?  You probably need a modal dialog for that case.  3) Never load images in the `paintComponent()` method.  Load it in the constructor and declare it as a class attribute for later use in paint.  4) Use `ImageIO.read()` for a blocking method to load images.  5) Use a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()` instead of `Runnable`/`Thread`/`sleep()`.

Comment: *"but it's not my answer exactly!"*  (Take your pick.)  a) That is why I entered it as a comment, rather than an answer.  b) Feel free to ask for your money back.

Answer (score 1):

You can not place an instance of `Clock` in a `JPanel`. That hardly makes sense!

Clock is a `JFrame`, and so it would not make sense to place a `JFrame` inside of a `JPanel`.

(Unless you are looking for `Internal Frames`): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

However, it sounds more like you want a `ClockPanel` inside of another `JPanel` which is in another `JFrame`.

Something like this should work:

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new ClockPanel());
jFrame.add(panel);
```

That is, unless the class from which you are executing these lines of code is not in the same package as class `Clock`.
In that case, make your `ClockPanel` class `public`.

Comment: While the question lacks focus, this answer is nonsense. Non-public (specifically 'default') classes can be used in other classes in the same package.  -1

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nonsense? I can not assume that the referencing class is in the same package. If not, `ClockPanel`, a `default/protected` class, could not be referenced. Furthermore, the O.P. didn't describe exactly which issue he/or she was having, so I took a shoot at class visibility.

Comment: Good edit.  Down-vote removed. ..+1 for the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

You can place this part of code as your `Clock` class :

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

class Clock extends JLabel
{
    Timer t = null;

    //get current time
    public String timeNow()
    {
       Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
       int hrs = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int min = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       int sec = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

       String time = zero(hrs)+":"+zero(min)+":"+zero(sec);

       return time;
    }

     public String zero(int num)
     {
       String number=( num < 10) ? ("0"+num) : (""+num);
       return number;                                    //Add leading zero if needed
     }

    public Clock()
    {
        super();
        setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));    //create font instance);

        setBorder(new BevelBorder(1));
        t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DoChangeText();
            }
        });

        t.start();
    }

    public void DoChangeText()
    {
        this.setText(timeNow());
    }
}
```

You can use it to add in JFrame as following code :

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    Clock c = new Clock();
    c.setSize(250, 100);
    c.setLocation(12, 100 );

    frame.add(c);
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);`  Unnecessary & fragile. -1

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Maybe he wants to set location and size manually, so, He use setLayout(null)!!!!! Please dont give him `- VOTE`, I think it is `Unnecessary and fragile`! Please note that `What I want to see in a technical forum is people using **&** in official sentence!!!`

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Note that, it is only the example of usage! I think it is not necessary to vote me down!!! IS IT OK ?

Comment: *"Maybe he wants to set location and size manually, so, He.."* ..implements that logic in a custom layout, and set that layout as the layout of the parent container.  **If** the developer in question is clever enough to know where to exactly position components across different screen sizes, PLAFs, JRE versions, OS' etc.  OTOH a simple addition of a few components to a GUI is best served by using the common layouts, perhaps in combination.  For more on the matter, see [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) on Oracle forums.